# Python: Error al instalar Scrapy [Versión 3.xx]

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, python-requests, scrapy

Estoy trabajando con python en un entorno virtual independiente para no generar conflictos con otros proyectos y no puedo instalar la librería de Scrapy.

Versión de python : 3.6.4
S.O               : Windows 10.

Comando utilizado para instalar la librería Scrapy :

```
pip install scrapy
```

[image: Vista de comando utilizado para instalar Scrapy]

La instalación transcurre con normalidad hasta que aparece el primer error.

[image: Failed building wheel for Twisted]

y finalmente me aparece esto en la consola :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me gustaría saber como poder solucionarlo, ya que, no puedo ejecutar el comando
"scrapy" [debido a que no se instala correctamente].

Espero atento sus respuestas, Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Algunos paquetes python tienen partes escritas en lenguaje C. En este caso o bien tienes un compilador C instalado en tu plataforma para que `pip` lo use cuando lo necesite, o bien buscas la forma de instalar una "versión binaria" para tu plataforma (en la que las partes en C ya vienen compiladas y no necesitas el compilador).

Parece que tu plataforma es Windows, por lo que tienes estas alternativas:

- Instalar [`Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools`](http://landinghub.visualstudio.com/visual-cpp-build-tools). De hecho eso es lo que te sugiere la última línea antes del error en rojo.
- Ya que aparentemente el problema ocurre cuando se intenta instalar Twisted (que scrapy necesita), puedes tratar de instalar primero la versión binaria de Twisted. Según [su documentación](https://twistedmatrix.com/trac/wiki/Downloads) lo siguiente debería funcionar (no lo he probado):

  ```
  pip install Twisted[windows_platform]
  ```

No obstante, aún si la segunda opción te funciona, no está de mas que tengas instalado un compilador C, pues tarde o temprano podrás encontrarte con un paquete Python que lo necesita y para el que no hay versión binaria.

Comment: Solo agregaría, que en caso de instalar un compilador C/C++, éste debería ser el mismo con el que se ha compilado originalmente el interprete `python`, en este caso el error lo dice, se requiere El C++ de Microsoft, versión 14. Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Para instalar scrapy, lo hice de anaconda 3.
Abrí el prompt Anaconda como administrador y escribe:

```
conda install -c conda-forge scrapy
```

con eso deberia funcionar bien. Si dice que necesitas una version nueva de MS C++ 9.0 o superior, a mi me resolvio el problema desisntar tanto pyhton como anaconda e instalar todo de nuevo.